# Trailing period after section number in Rmd notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, rnotebook

I have an R notebook like the following:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: 
  html_notebook:
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
---
# First section   
## Subsection
Some text

# Second section
```

When rendered to Preview Notebook in RStudio, it generates numbered section titles like `1 First section`, `1.1 Subsection` etc. What if I want it to add a dot at the end of the number, i.e. produce `1. First section`, `1.1. Subsection` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS for styling these numbers.

For instance, these notebook has dot after header numbers as you want:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: 
  html_notebook:
    number_sections: true
    toc: true
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.header-section-number::after {
  content: ".";
}
```

# First section   
## Subsection
Some text

# Second section
````